# Can't seem to win installing gulp globally on my Windows 10 machine

Tags: gulp

I keep getting this message when trying to install gulp globally, i have tried a lot of the solutions and nothing seem to work for me.

$ npm install --global gulp-cli
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js

- gulp-cli@2.3.0
  added 235 packages from 163 contributors and updated 1 package in 40.499s

Comment: This message is just warning that a dependency of gulp is deprecated, the installation should be successful. Did you add npm to the Windows path?

Comment: Thank you for the response I'm checking if I can add the path. I will let you know if when it's done.